# Java SE 8: Would a Java 7 compiled JAR be compatible completely with Java 8?

Tags: java, compatibility

I compiled my old JAR files in Java 7 and my production environment has Java 8. Is there anything I need to be careful about directly deploying the JAR files onto Java 8 Environment? I test ran them on Java 8 and it worked fine. Could I encounter any problems or should I be fine? I was wondering this because I was debating removing Java 8 and installing Java 7.

EDIT: A side question: Do companies update their code when they update their Java version? I can't imagine how painful this must be so have your app working on a previous version and then completely fail on the new version.

Comment: I remember going from 6 to 7 and encountering bugs, especially with sorting. The change to the default sort (introducing TimSort) introduced a check that caused buggy comparison algorithms to fail loudly instead of fail silently. As it turned out, our "bug" never manifested with our usecases because it sorted itself out by the end. But TimSort detected the bug in an internal check (to check for conditions that should never occur) and threw exceptions. The only real way to know is to test, test, test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering this because I was debating removing Java 8 and installing Java 7.

I assume you mean the other way around?

Java attempts to maintain backwards compatibility as far as it can, so theoretically at least you should be ok.

In practice however, issues do sometimes come up, so I'd advocate testing thoroughly. These may be due to regression bugs, or (more likely in my experience) buggy code that might have run fine under Java 7, but not under 8. (FWIW, I had a couple of FX apps that mixbehaved under 8 but ran fine under 7, it turned out both were due to bugs in my code that coincidentally had no unusual side effects when running with 7.)

Comment: No I didn't mean that the other way around. The JAR is compiled on 7 and runs perfectly on 7. A better worded question would be, should I just stick with 7 since it works great and not bother upgrading to 8? I tested on 8 and it worked fine as well, however, I am scared that something might go wrong on 8.

Comment: @user1757703 Ah ok, in that case then I'd definitely advocate keeping the major Java version consistent across your dev / production environments. Whether you choose to upgrade them both to 8 or downgrade to 7 is your call (but personally I'd always favour upgrading unless you have a good reason to do otherwise.)

Answer (score 1):

Usually, there should be no problem. Otherwise you would have a hard time to use any third-party libraries not explicitly compiled for Java SE 8.

I recommend to run your automated tests on a continuous integration server such as Jenkins using Java SE 8 and see if you have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

It is safe to package Java 8 application with jar dependencies compiled with Java 7. Given that said, however, keep in mind differences in JDK 7 and 8, that can result the same Java code could behave differently when running on JDK 8 vs JDK 7 (refer to JDK 8 release notes)